# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource when using spark-submit

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

The following error is present when using spark submit... Otherwise works well pyspark:

> : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
> com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource. Please find packages at
> http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:679)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:733)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:967)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:304)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Here's the code that I'm running:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll")
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2")
    .getOrCreate()
)

people = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("Bilbo Baggins", 50),
        ("Gandalf", 1000),
        ("Thorin", 195),
        ("Balin", 178),
        ("Kili", 77),
        ("Dwalin", 169),
        ("Oin", 167),
        ("Gloin", 158),
        ("Fili", 82),
        ("Bombur", None),
    ],
    ["name", "age"],
)

people.write.format("mongo").mode("append").save()
```

Comment: Hi Did you resolve the error, please post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--packages` while submitting spark job using spark-submit.

```
spark-submit --master <url> --class <className> --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2
```

Comment: they did. See the line `.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2")`